# Trigger Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline Scan from another job

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline

Is it possible to trigger Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now action for a Jenkins Multibranch Pipeline from another Job? I have certain issues integrating my old version of Gitlab with Pipeline Jobs in Jenkins and came upon such a workaround.

Alternatively, would it be possible to trigger Scan Multibranch Pipeline Now with a notifyCommit web hook?

The purpose of this would be to Scan Multibranch Pipeline whenever a change occurs in the Git repo, so that new branches are detected after such a change. 
Another purpose, which I am unable to achieve otherwise (except for periodic polling per branch which is plain evil to me), is to trigger build of branches affected by given changeset. [I use old GitLab (7.8) which does not work with the ordinary Gitlab plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-plugin/issues/405) and the [Gitlab Hook plugin does not work with pipeline jobs](https://github.com/jenkinsci/gitlab-hook-plugin/issues/31), so my workaround would be to have an non-Pipeline Job to be triggered by Gitlab Hook plugin and this job would in turn trigger  Scan Multibranch Pipeline.

Comment: What's the exact purpose? Would you like to run the other job or make Jenkins detect a new repo / that you created in GitLab?

Comment: I have answered your question by editing the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out that simple notifyCommit web hook did the job